# Histogram proper fitting

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have got the  10,000 values for my data using Matlab. When I plotted the histogram and fitted it with normal distribution I got the following figure [image]

Is there some mistake in this histogram fitting or what should I do to scale it properly.

Comment: Related questions: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473064/fit-data-to-normal-distribution) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496804/manipulate-data-to-better-fit-a-gaussian-distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you could just call

```
histfit(your_data,num_bins)
```