# Transform data to fit normal distribution

Tags: matlab, data-binding, normal-distribution, data-fitting

I have a rather easy-to-understand question.

I have a set of data and I want to estimate how good this data fit a **standard normal distribution**. To do so, I start with my code:

```
[f_p,m_p] = hist(data,128);
f_p = f_p/trapz(m_p,f_p);

x_th = min(data):.001:max(data);
y_th = normpdf(x_th,0,1);   

figure(1)
bar(m_p,f_p)
hold on
plot(x_th,y_th,'r','LineWidth',2.5)
grid on
hold off
```

Fig. 1 will look like the one below:

[image]

Easy to see that the fit is quite poor, altough the bell-shape can be spotted. The main problem resides therefore in the **variance** of my data.

To find out the proper number of occurrances my data-bins should own, I do this:

```
f_p_th = interp1(x_th,y_th,m_p,'spline','extrap');
figure(2)
bar(m_p,f_p_th)
hold on
plot(x_th,y_th,'r','LineWidth',2.5)
grid on
hold off
```

which will result in the following fig. :

[image]

Hence, the question is: how can I scale my data-block to match the Gaussian distribution as in **Fig.2** ?

**CAUTION**

I wanna stress the focus on one point: I **don't** wanna **find** the **best distribution fitting the data**; the **problem** is **reversed**: starting from my data, I'd like to manipulate it in such a way that,in the end, its distribution reasonably fits the Gaussian one.

Unfortunately, at the moment, I don't have a real idea on how to perform this data "filter", "transform" or "manipulation".

Any support would be welcome.

Comment: How is this question any different from your previous last two questions ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496804/manipulate-data-to-better-fit-a-gaussian-distribution) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473064/fit-data-to-normal-distribution))?

Comment: I didn't get any valuable answer up to now! So I try to tune the question in order to make it more reader-friendly.

Comment: I think the best way to do it would be by _editing_, not by posting new questions. But that's just my opinion, of course.

Comment: I do agree with your opinion, I actually feel rather dumb when re-posting the same question thousand times. Unfortunately I really would like to come up with a solution to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe what you are interested in is rank-based inverse normal transformation. Basically you rank the data first and then convert it to a normal distribution:

```
rank = tiedrank( data );
p = rank / ( length(rank) + 1 ); %# +1 to avoid Inf for the max point
newdata = norminv( p, 0, 1 );
```

Comment: currently this is the procedure I would follow, but I need to test it more thoroughly.

Comment: @fpe: Please don't leave the question without accepting some answer. Don't also forget to upvote those that you found useful.

Comment: sorry but I'm on Easter holiday at the moment, with only limited access to the web. I'll fix everything next week.

Comment: your answer looks like the one I've been searching for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do seems to match the problem of trying to find how random a set of data is. Supergaussian pdfs are those which have a greater probability around zero (or the mean, whatever it may be) than the Gaussian distribution, and are consequently more "sharply peaked" - much like your example. An example of this type of distribution is the Laplace distribution. Subgaussian pdfs are the opposite.

A measure of a dataset's closeness to the Gaussian distribution can be given in many ways... often this is done by using either the fourth-order moment, kurtosis (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis - MATLAB function kurt), or an information-theoretic measure such as negentropy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negentropy ). Kurtosis is a bit dodgy if you have lots of outliers because the error gets raised to the power of 4, so negentropy is better.

If you don't understand the term "fourth-order moment", read a statistics textbook.

A comparison of these, and several other, measures of randomness (Gaussianity) is given in many texts on independent component analysis (ICA), as it is a core concept. A good resource on this is the book Independent Component Analysis, by Hyvarinen and Oja - http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Independent_Component_Analysis.html?id=96D0ypDwAkkC .

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to really understand what this question, or your other recent similar ones, have been asking exactly.

Perhaps you have data that is normally distributed, and you want to make it be normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation 1?

If so, then subtract `mu` from your data and divide it by `sigma`, where `mu` is the mean of the data and `sigma` is its standard deviation. If your original data is normally distributed, then the result should be data that is normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

There's a function `zscore` in Statistics Toolbox to do exactly this for you.

But perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: I know this trick and I applied it already, but it sounds to me as "faking" time series, since the distribution is not changed at all and I think it does not garantee for the gaussianity of the data-block. but I'm not an expert.

Comment: this is actually a very good aproach for validation, thank you