# How do I transform a column of data into a normal distribution in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, data-analysis, numerical-analysis, probability-density

If I have a vector a, which is not follow normal distribution. How do I transform them into normal distribution in MATLAB?

which means I create a new vector b that follow the normal distribution and have the information of a.

Comment: What do you mean by: *transform the data into normal distribution*?

Comment: exactly yes, in matlab.

Comment: @PeterZhu - knedlsepp asked you for **clarification** on your statement.  Simply saying "exactly" does not clarify anything.

Comment: @rayryeng,@knedlsepp, I mean I had a vector a, but not follow normal distribution, so I want to create a new vector b base on vector a witch follow normal distribution and represent the information of a.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transform data to fit normal distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549836/transform-data-to-fit-normal-distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I get you right:

assume you have a vector **a**,
and you would like to get a normal distribution that represents it.

[correct me if I am wrong]

```
>>a = randn(2); //your vector 
>>x=[-10:0.1:10]; 
>> y = gaussmf(x,[std(a) mean(a)]); //std(a)=sigma,mean(a)=mu
>> plot(x,y);
```